# How to split and parse a big text file in python in a memory-efficient way?

Tags: python, parsing, file-io, ascii

I have quite a big text file to parse.
The main pattern is as follows:

```
step 1

[n1 lines of headers]

  3  3  2
 0.25    0.43   12.62    1.22    8.97
12.89   89.72   34.87   55.45   17.62
 4.25   16.78   98.01    1.16   32.26
 0.90    0.78   11.87
step 2

[n2 != n1 lines of headers]

  3  3  2
 0.25    0.43   12.62    1.22    8.97
12.89   89.72   34.87   55.45   17.62
 4.25   16.78   98.01    1.16   32.26
 0.90    0.78   11.87
step 3

[(n3 != n1) and (n3 !=n2) lines of headers]

  3  3  2
 0.25    0.43   12.62    1.22    8.97
12.89   89.72   34.87   55.45   17.62
 4.25   16.78   98.01    1.16   32.26
 0.90    0.78   11.87
```

in other words:

> A separator: step #
>
> Headers of known length (line numbers, not bytes)
>
> Data 3-dimensional shape: nz, ny, nx
>
> Data: fortran formating, ~10 floats/line in the original dataset

I just want to extract the data, convert them to floats, put it in a numpy array and ndarray.reshape it to the shapes given.

I've already done a bit of programming... The main idea is

1. to get the offsets of each separator first ("step X")
2. skip nX (n1, n2...) lines + 1 to reach the data
3. read bytes from there all the way to the next separator.

I wanted to avoid regex at first since these would slow things down a lot. It already takes 3-4 minutes just to get the first step done (browsing the file to get the offset of each part).

The problem is that I'm basically using `file.tell()` method to get the separator positions:

```
[file.tell() - len(sep) for line in file if sep in line]
```

The problem is two-fold:

1. for smaller files, `file.tell()` gives the right separator positions, for longer files, it does not. I suspect that `file.tell()` should not be used in loops neither using explicit `file.readline()` nor using the implicit `for line in file` (I tried both). I don't know, but the result is there: with big files, `[file.tell() for line in file if sep in line]` does **not** give systematically the position of the line right after a separator.
2. len(sep) does not give the right offset correction to go back at the beginning of the "separator" line. `sep` is a string (bytes) containing the first line of the file (the first separator).

Does anyone knows how I should parse that?

NB: I find the offsets first because I want to be able to browse inside the file: I might just want the 10th dataset or the 50000th one...

## 1- Finding the offsets

```
sep = "step "
with open("myfile") as f_in:
    offsets = [fin.tell() for line in fin if sep in line]
```

As I said, this is working in the simple example, but not on the big file.

New test:

```
sep = "step "
offsets = []
with open("myfile") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if sep in line:
            print line
            offsets.append(f_in.tell())
```

The line printed corresponds to the separators, no doubt about it. But the offsets obtained with `f_in.tell()` do not correspond to the next line. I guess the file is buffered in memory and as I try to use `f_in.tell()` in the implicit loop, I do not get the current position but the end of the buffer. This is just a wild guess.

Comment: Have you looked into using the [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module at all? (This is somewhat independent of your question; you just mentioned browsing a large file.)

Comment: Yes, I've looked to `mmap`, but I don't really see how this would solve my problem... That would allow me to read the file "at once" in memory but that wouldn't solve my splitting problem, would it? This file is ~16GB (using 64bit OS, so `mmap` should be usable) but I will produce bigger files.

Comment: So your question is how to find the offsets? And "for smaller files, file.tell() gives the right separator positions, for longer files, it does not" I'm pretty sure that `tell` will give the right position for longer files.

Comment: I should try once again, but I'm pretty sure of that. Is file browsing multithreaded? When I just try `[file.tell() for line in file if sep in line]` I'm absolutely positive that the corresponding line is **not** always the one right after the separator. I usually get a line in the middle of the data section.

Comment: Is it possible that the "step N" separators in the real file are not at the beginning of the line? As `tell()` returns the offset to feed into `seek()` and not a line number. Have you tried storing those indexes and then trying and opening the files on those spots?

Comment: `tell()` gives the file offset in bytes. In the real script, the separators are actually all the same so I just did: `sep = f_in.readline()` as the very first line of my script and I really compare `sep` and `line`. This was confirmed by the second approach which gave me the current matching line (the `print` statement). But when I try to use the offsets afterwards, I'm in the middle of my data.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that iterating over the file object is doing some buffering, and thus the current location in the file object might not be at the line being processed in the list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, I've considered it (see the last 4 lines of the [too long] question).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: `for`-loops on a file and `tell()` do not get along very well. Just like mixing `for i in file` and `file.readline()` raises an error.

So, use `file.tell()` with `file.readline()` or `file.read()` *only*.

**Never ever use**:

```
for line in file:
    [do stuff]
    offset = file.tell()
```

This is really a shame but that's the way it is.